# How can I dynamically execute function in current scope and add it as property of the calling function?

Tags: python, namespaces, code-generation, exec, abstract-syntax-tree

I have some code like this:

```
def f1():
  <some stuff here>
.
.
.

@mylib.codegen
def f2(args):
  f1()
  <some more stuff here>
```

mylib.py :

```
def codegen(fn):
  src = inspect.getsource(fn)
  original_ast = ast.parse(src)
  new_ast = transform_ast(original_ast)
  code_obj = compile(new_ast, '<auto-generated>', 'exec')
  myscope = {}
  exec code_obj in myscope
  fn.generated_fn = myscope['name']   # Where name is the binding created by execing code_obj
```

To summarize, `mylib.codegen` is a decorator which parses code of f, creates an ast of another function based on ast of `f`, execs code of generated function to get a callable function and sets callable function as a property of `f`. That means when `f2` is imported the first time, `f2` dynamically gets another function as property of itself.

Generated function also needs to call `f1` but it can't find `f1` in `myscope`. If somehow Python allowed inlining, and I had inlined code of `mylib.codegen`, everything would have been fine but I don't think Python allows inlining of code. 
How do I set things up so that generated code object is execed in namespace of caller function?

Comment: And the function globals scope can be found in `fn.func_globals`; perhaps update `myscope` with that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Thanks ,`fn.func_globals` worked. 

I just need to do something. To give you a high level idea, for every function we write a function to do something with all the data required by the function. Manually writing and maintaining all this code is repetitive, I'm trying to automate that.

Answer (score 0):

The `fn.func_globals` contains the global namespace for a given function; you'll need it to be able to exec the transformed and recompiled code object:

```
myscope = {}
myscope.update(fn.func_globals)
```

Do not use `fn.func_globals` directly; you wouldn't want to overwrite items in that namespace.